# replacing an entire line in from a file C++

Tags: c++, file, replace

So I've been playing with code and I'm stuck with finding how to replace the line found. I'm able to find the name and add the 'new_gpa' to the section but it outputs the final result in the same file but without replacing the original score and name.

how could I remove the original line found along with the gpa? and also store the new values to the file.

```
cristian 2.1
rachel 3.0
```

name search: cristian

new file:

```
cristian 2.1
rachel 3.0
cristian 4.1
```

The code is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string name;
    int offset;
    string line;

    ifstream read_file;
    read_file.open("alpha.dat", std::ios_base::app);
    cout << "Please enter your name: \n";
    cin>> name;

    if (read_file.is_open())
    {
        while(!read_file.eof())
        {
            getline(read_file,line);

            if((offset = line.find(name)) != string::npos)
            {
                cout <<"the word has been found: \n";
                //cout << line  //example to display
                //new code
                istringstream iss ( line );
                string thisname;
                double gpa;
                double new_gpa = 2.1;

                if( iss >> thisname >> gpa)
                {
                    if (thisname == name)
                    {
                        cout << name <<endl;
                        cout << gpa <<endl;
                        ofstream myfile;
                        myfile.open("alpha.dat",std::ios_base::app);
                        myfile << " \n" << name << " " << gpa+ new_gpa;
                        myfile.close();
                        read_file.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remember, a file is just a stream of bytes. A "line" is simply an interpretation of the `\n` (newline) character (or `\r\n` on windows).  Removing a line is not a simple operation: You have shift the remainder of the file *backwards* in the file, to replace the bytes from the "removed" line.

Comment: Also, your indentation is hideous - I can't even look at your code.

Comment: Can't you just read it into a vector structure and make the changes in the vector and then write everything back to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You open file with `std::ios_base::app`, which means all you output operations are performed at the end of file, appending the content to the current file. But what you want to do is modify the data at the original place. So you should open file with `std::ios_base::in`, and function `seekp` can help you in the next step.